# Regular Expressions problems

Tags: java, regex

I got this html code and i want to search one  tag:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="some.jpg"/></a> 
<a href="http://www.google.com">some text at link</a>
```

This regex return all code and how i can find only one tag:

```
<a.*\\</a\\>
```

Comment: what do you mean by one tag and all code?

Comment: this return me <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="some.jpg"/></a> 
<a href="http://www.google.com">some text at link</a> in 1 match but i want 2 matches

Comment: I'd use a HTML parser (eg. Jsoup) for this kind of problem, and not a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by making your regex non greedy.. i.e adding a `?` after `.*` (which is greedy by default and tries to capture as much as possible)

```
<a.*?\\</a\\>
    ↑
```

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 1 minute" :P i waiting